# CSP header blocks file download in iframe in firefox only

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, content-security-policy

I am launching my website in an iframe. I am using the following CSP headers:

```
default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors: 'self'; img-src 'self' data:
```

I am trying to download a file from the client side using:

```
var a = doc.createElement('a');
a.download ='download.pdf';
a.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfdata;
doc.body.appendChild(a);
a.onclick = function () {
    a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
};
a.click();
```

In Chrome & IE, the file is being downloaded successfully. But for Firefox I see the following CSP error:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcK... (“default-src
>   self”).

I am unable to understand why it’s failing only for Firefox.

Comment: This seems issue with Firefox. I have logged a bug at Bugzilla

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1365502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Firefox issue. I have logged following bug against this issue and it is now confirmed by Bugzilla team.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1365502

You can also check following url to reproduce this issue
http://data-uri-download-csp.bitballoon.com/